# Setting can only see and prohibit download

Tags: python, python-3.7, pydrive

I have a batch of files

I know how to query files

```py
drive.ListFile({'q': "'id' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

Now I want to batch files

Setting can only view and prohibit download

But I don't know how to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding your GoogleDrive file.

Use copyRequiresWriterPermission = True.

Then upload.

```py
file['copyRequiresWriterPermission'] = True
file.Upload()
```